# Does TypeScript discriminated union with optional discriminant allow invalid value to be assigned?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if the following case is correct:

```js
type P =
  | { foo: boolean; bar?: undefined }
  | { foo: boolean; bar: boolean; baz: boolean };
const p: P = { foo: true, baz: true };
```

What I expected is that the only valid values that I can assign to `p` are:

1. `{ foo: true }`
2. `{ foo: true, bar: true, baz: true }`

It's easy to show that if `bar` is not optional in both cases, then it works as expected though.

And yes, I could possibly just remove `bar` from the first part of the union, but I want to use this type as React props and it must be "discriminated" somehow.

I noticed that all examples demonstrating this on the Internet don't contain any additional fields so maybe the only way to do this is to include all the fields in both parts of the union but with different types/optionality?

Comment: Only one field has to be shared, and that's the discriminator. Sadly TS doesn't let you use 2+ fields, **even if they are only on one side**

Comment: It's valid; if you don't want to allow `baz` in the first union member, you should do what you did with `bar` and write `{foo: boolean; bar?: undefined; baz?: undefined} | {foo: boolean; bar: boolean; baz: boolean}`.  Excess properties are not invalid according to the type system; there are some cases where you will get warned for excess properties but those are in only particular situations and not because there's anything invalid about them.

Comment: ...That being said, it is currently considered a *bug* that excess property warnings don't kick in for the situation you have here, see [ms/TS#39050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39050).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, totally makes sense to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are *open* and *extendible*, not *closed*, or *sealed*, or "*exact*" (as described in the feature request [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  A value of an object type is allowed to have extra properties not mentioned in the type.  If this *weren't* the case, then [extending](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) interfaces or classes would break type compatibility:

```
interface Foo { bar: string; }
interface Baz extends Foo { qux: number; }
const baz: Baz = { bar: "abc", qux: 123 };
const foo: Foo = baz; // okay
```

There is a feature called [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) which warns you if you assign an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) with extra properties to something that doesn't expect them:

```
const fooDirect: Foo = { bar: "abc", qux: 123 }; // error!
// --------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 
// 'qux' does not exist in type 'Foo'.
```

That's not because the assignment is *invalid* (at least not according to the structural type system); after all, the equivalent assignment `const foo: Foo = baz;` is allowed.  The warning happens because the knowledge of that `qux` property is completely lost after that assignment, and this might be a mistake. Compare to `const foo: Foo = baz;` where `baz` is still accessible afterward and therefore the knowledge still exists.

So excess property warnings aren't a type safety issue; they're more of a linter feature.  And it can be a useful feature, but unfortunately it causes a lot of confusion and sometimes I think it might be more trouble than it's worth.  It makes people think that TypeScript object types are exact when they aren't, and then they complain when people sidestep that feature by assigning values to intermediate variables or when using part of the language that doesn't enforce excess property warnings like copying to an intermediate variable, or like what's happening in this question with a discriminated union with an optional discriminant.

---

That means the assignment here:

```
type P =
    { foo: boolean, bar?: undefined } |
    { foo: boolean, bar: boolean, baz: boolean };

const p: P = { foo: true, baz: true };
```

would be *valid* whether or not you got an excess property warning.  There's nothing in the type system that says you couldn't assign `{foo: true, baz: true}` to `{foo: boolean, bar?: undefined}`.  If you want that assignment to be *invalid*, then you need to change `P` to actually prohibit the `baz` key.  Well, TypeScript can't really prohibit keys, but it does support [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) so that the property is either missing or `undefined`, which is similar.  Like this:

```
type P =
    { foo: boolean, bar?: undefined, baz?: never} |
    { foo: boolean, bar: boolean, baz: boolean };
const p: P = { foo: true, baz: true }; // error
```

That gives you the error you want and should be an error even if you try to copy it to some intermediate variable first... because you're not relying on excess property warnings.

---

All that being said, the behavior you're seeing here is considered a bug in TypeScript, as reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#39050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39050).  Excess property warnings are supposed to happen when you mention a property not present in the relevant member of a discriminated union.  But it looks like this doesn't happen when the discriminant property is optional and missing.  So maybe this behavior will someday be changed to the way you want it.

But again, to be painfully clear, even if they fix that, it's just an excess property warning that can be easily circumvented, as you can see if you change your discriminant to be required:

```
type P =
    { foo: boolean, bar: 0 } | { foo: boolean, bar: 1, baz: boolean };
const p: P = { foo: true, bar: 0, baz: true }; // error you wanted
// -----------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~

const indirect = { foo: true, bar: 0, baz: true } as const;
const pIndirect: P = indirect; // no error
```

So you probably want to use the optional-`never` approach anyway.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7IEZxQBcyAzmFKAOYDcyAvgFCiSyIoBCcAXshAB6QQAE1JpMOZAEcArvxIgZAWzzQ6TBOhDl8PEl14BeSQWLIARHDwJzAGmlySARgBMAZgY1Gm7WGQxMEgwsYwJuOgB6COR0AGs4AE9Gby0dAPQAEWAoCAQwIIljXFMSS2s7B3lkVw96SOjoKHQoAEJGKOQAWm6e3r7+gd6APmQAP3GJ8fbogHk8ACtcvwAbYFY4ZeQlRJiQZYSyAAdc4BgD2JB0AHcQZEOm46gwYAhSezgRZGnkAHJZfh+yGE6FeyEufgEwB0oGQYASx1+wR+ADpkiA4EpXod2MgZpQqDhGMhibD4SgAArIQxEkm03DpEh4TDLCAfeymAD8JBkIggMFAEGEDGQAB8abTifTAvhmayQOzCIzZWzdNwlegWR9POLkD4dIcSJSiv5pRQZBAFWrYVBzdqmIx0ZjSNikGhgPxCbS4QijTq6Sb0OrNfLdFAucgecI+QLhJbwyAIAA3aDCsUSklSwMyjVyhVmJk5lVhINy7W0vV+A3II2SBnW82WkhmlB1ZAdRrNRj2tEYrE4gASSiUnpJ3opVL9GYDJaLiuQAAZU7XpQXg3nnI3s8GyySK3dDVTl1nm+uF5vm542w0oE0oMgEugZMgrh9IMIdR1Bl-v90RpN-8k5apH4oDCNkSyHpmTY2haoYkPO54wcKcBiBWXhAb4dwAJIiOBeQHsYoF4WA9RglgHZQF2yRAA)